# Wordpress wp_enqueue_style version not works

Tags: wordpress

I want browser to load `css/js` files when user refresh.

So, I read about `wp_enqueue_script()` in [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

```
wp_enqueue_style( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, string $media = 'all' )
```

As you can see, the `$ver` parameter is there!

But, it didn't work.

These are what I did.

1. change file name.

   get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css'

   get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/my_style.css'

but browser load my_style.css. yes , wp_enqueue_style() works well.

2. add ver directly

   get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css?ver=0.001'

   get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css?ver=1.0.0'

   get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css?ver=abcde'

but, browser just load `style.css` without `?ver=~~`.

3. Add random value on version parameter
   but, browser just load `style.css` without `?ver=~~`.

Why?

Answer (score 3):

If you can  use **wp_register_style** functions,if you want to add a random version number at the end of the css file you are attaching. pass a random (version) number rand(111,9999) to 4th parameter.Examples are here.You can add this code in your **functions.php**

```
wp_register_style( 'custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-style.css', array(), rand(111,9999), 'all' );
```

Comment: Thanks! this will be helpful!

Comment: sorry , some people don't like upload screenshot because of mobile phone

Answer (score 1):

You should load css with [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) the right way.
For example, put this code in your theme [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file:

```
function addStyles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'your-theme-name', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', array(), 'your-version');
}
add_action('wp_head', 'addStyles');
```

And it worked:

[image]

Comment: What about add this in your `header.php`: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()."/style.css?ver=123"?>">`

Comment: I see, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found answer myself. And I think this would be help to someone later.

CSS version.

```
function rpf_prevent_css_cache($src, $handle) {
  if ( $handle == 'rpf-main' ) {
    $src .= '?ver='.time();
  }
   eturn $src;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'rpf_prevent_css_cache', 100, 2 );
```

Javascript version.

```
function rpf_prevent_js_cache($src, $handle) {
  if ( $handle == 'rpf-main' || $handle == 'rpf-functions' ) {
    $src .= '?ver='.time();
  }
  return $src;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'rpf_prevent_js_cache', 100, 2 );
```

As you can see, I just add time() to file ref version by using filter.

rpf-main, rpf-functions is my custom handle!